# can I return the iterators in that manner?

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like my c++ code to be as encapsulated as i can is this manner of return the iterators is ok?

```
const map<string,bool>::iterator getFollowers() {

        return followers.begin();

    }

    const map<string,bool>::iterator getFollowing() {

        return following.begin();

    }
```

the full code:

```
#ifndef twitClient_twitUser_h
#define twitClient_twitUser_h

#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class user {
    string username;
    map<string,bool> followers;
    map<string,bool> following;
    string name;


public:

    user(string username):username(username) {
        followers [username] = false;
        following [username] = false;
    }

    bool removeFollower (string friendName);
    bool addFollower(string friendName);
    bool stopFollowing(string friendName);
    bool startFollowing(string friendName);

    const map<string,bool>::iterator getFollowers() {

        return followers.begin();

    }

    const map<string,bool>::iterator getFollowing() {

        return following.begin();

    }


};
```

Comment: Why don't make functions like `const map<string, bool>&getFollowers() const` so I can access data, but not change it. It's much more convinient, because iterator doesn't give me full control. Also, for many algorithms end iterator is also needed. So I suggest you not to use such incapsulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothong wrong with your approach, except that you may want to add const access methods too,  foe example

```
map<string,bool>::const_iterator getFollowers() const;
```

Plus you want to add access to the `end()` iterators too.

Concerning encapsulation, you encapsulate the map, but your clients are exposed to `map<string, bool>::iterator`. There's a very interesting article about hiding those dependencies [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html). It is by no means trivial, but it is still worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Encapsulation has several meanings.

- In its lighter form, it means that the class has full control over the encapsulated members, which could be the case here (if you returned a `const_iterator`)
- In its heavier form, it means that the class implementation details do not leak into the exterior word, which is *not* the case here

So, you do not let others get control over your internals (good) but you still expose the implementation details, breaking clients if you ever change how `followers` or `following` is implemented under the covers.

A possible solution is to introduce a looping construct (such as foreach):

```
template <typename Pred>
void user::foreachFollower(Pred& p) const {
    for (auto const& f: followers) { p(f); }
}
```

This is more flexible, because should you change the map from `<string, bool>` to `<string, int>` (to count the numbers instead), you can always alter the function:

```
template <typename Pred>
void user::foreachFollower(Pred& p) const {
    for (std::pair<std::string, bool> const& f: followers) { p(f); }
}
```

So that your clients are not broken. They are also elaborate tricks to detect whether the client can handle a `std::pair<std::string, int>` or not, but they are (a tad) harder to implement.

---

On another note, just giving the `begin` iterator is not enough, they also need the `end` one.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be some design issues if you consider this question further. Seems you will keep many containers in this setup and set a follower/following bool to state whether a condition is true. Back to this in a minute.

Passing back an iterator can be very dangerous if the container is manipulated from another method before / during use. So for your question I would think about passing a reference to the container to be analysed/manipulated and if multi threading is used (in these multi core days we need to always think about this) use mutex to make the container thread safe or [active object](http://herbsutter.com/2010/07/12/effective-concurrency-prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-naked-threads/) type design and a simple safe queue implementation.

For this setup it may be better to consider a matrix type design if you have a closed group of users or if you have a many to many situation then perhaps consider something like [boost multi index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). This may provide a clearer more extensible design.